# Try to add Taskbar Icon

Tags: java, jframe, frame, taskbar

[1 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4Ewv.png)
[2 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UnmZ.png)

```
private void displayTaskbarIcon() {
        
    IEC iec = new IEC();
        
    StringBuffer installPathBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    installPathBuffer.append(iec.recoverIEFPath());
    installPathBuffer.append(java.io.File.separator);
    installPathBuffer.append("resources");
    installPathBuffer.append(java.io.File.separator);
    installPathBuffer.append("graphic");
    installPathBuffer.append(java.io.File.separator);
    installPathBuffer.append("icons");
    installPathBuffer.append(java.io.File.separator);
    installPathBuffer.append("3DSCompass.png");
                
    System.out.println(installPathBuffer.toString());
        
    Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(installPathBuffer.toString());
        
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setIconImage(img);
    frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setTitle("XCAD Jobs Client Configuration");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Trying to set Taskbar Icon using frame. It works but in left top corner small frame is also displayed with icon and configuration page. How I can fix this. I don't want that small frame at left top corner.

Comment: So, you want to specify a task bar icon, but not use a Swing (or I assume JavaFX) to do it?

Comment: Why are you using `JFrame`?. The way to add a taskbar icon is using `SystemTray.getSystemTray().add(new TrayIcon(image, tooltip))`

Comment: @Jorn That's not the taskbar, that's the system tray

Comment: Then by taksbar icon you just mean a shortcut? That's an OS-level thing, not an application-level thing.

Comment: @Jorn No, by "task bar" they mean the icon which represents the instance of the application which appears on the task bar (on Windows, that would the icon/button, which appears next to the start button) - The "system tray" typically appears on the opposite end (from the start button) and provides access to "system" features, like WiFi and sound

Comment: @MadProgrammer Okay, it's clear now. Then the answer is "don't do that, even if you can. Those buttons should always be tied to windows."

Comment: yes @MadProgrammer you are right. I want shortcut icon which appears on Taskbar while application is running. 
can we use JavaFX in Java version 17.0.4.1?

Comment: @AnjaliYadav The question though is, why don't you want a window?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Will window works for display the Taskbar icon?

Comment: @MadProgrammer      
Window window = new Window();
window.setIconImage(img);

can i use like this?